# Can I install my ubuntu /home partition in my mac extended journaled partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mac

I just bought a second hand late 2011 mac mini upgraded with a 500gb SSD, 8gb ram, running a new clean install El Capitan I just installed a few hours ago. I'd like to dual boot it with ubuntu gnome 16.04 with a separate /home partition but OSX is already installed with an extended partition. Once I shrink my OSX extended partition and create a primary /root partition can I shrink my logical Macintosh HD partition an install my dedicated /home partition as a logical partition with the unallocated space inside the OSX extended partition or should I just install it as a primary partition.

Disk Utility says it is using a GUID partition map

I've always thought a 500gb HDD/SSD was average sized. If It is considered small it's still more than enough for my purposes.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't care about primary and extended partitions. Do it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that with MBR partition tables, you can only have up to 4 partitions (typically 3 primary and 1 extended). Weigh that into your decision. You may have formatted your drive as GUID (probably typical for current Macs), and as such, can take as many primary partitions as you can throw at it.

My recommendation? With the small size of your SSD, I wouldn't setup Ubuntu with separate /root and /home partitions. You'll be wasting a lot of space. I'd set it up as one separate partition of its own, containing the entire Ubuntu installation.

Cheers, Al